# Blank Output on If...Else in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I've stumbled across an issue.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
                            if (($_GET['marking']) == "Theory") {
                                ?>
                                <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Please select month to mark/edit Attendance & Internal Assessment</h4>
                                <?php
                            }
                            else {
                                ?>
                                <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Please select month to mark/edit Attendance</h4>                              
                                <?php                                   
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <?php
                        //  echo $openclose;
                            if (isset($_GET['selectedcourseid'])) {
                                if ($openclose == "internals") {
                        ?>
                                        <a href="markattendanceint.php?selectedsubject=<?=$_GET['selectedsubject'];?>&selectedcourseid=<?=$_GET['selectedcourseid'];?>&type=<?=$_GET['type'];?>&selectedmonth=<?=$acceptmonth?>&marking=<?=$_GET['marking'];?>&teacherid=<?=$userid?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"><?=$acceptmonth?></button></a>
                        <?php }
                                else if ($openclose == "attendance") {
                        ?>
                                    <a href="markattendance.php?selectedsubject=<?=$_GET['selectedsubject'];?>&selectedcourseid=<?=$_GET['selectedcourseid'];?>&type=<?=$_GET['type'];?>&selectedmonth=<?=$acceptmonth?>&marking=<?=$_GET['marking'];?>&teacherid=<?=$userid?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"><?=$acceptmonth?></button></a>
                        <?php
                                }
                                else if ($openclose == "noresult") {
                                    echo ("Portal closed for your account only. Please contact the AO Office.");
                                }
                                else if ($openclose == "close") {
                                    echo ("Portal closed. Please contact the AO Office.");
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo ("Bhai tumse na ho payega");
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
```

$openclose has been set to attendance for this case. But no matter what value $openclose carries, I'm somehow not getting any output. No error, no button, nothing. Just a blank screen.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Below is an attached screenshot:
[Blank output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYz8t.jpg)

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_GET);` and show the results? As well as `var_dump($openclose);`

Comment: `$openclose` is embedded within a check for `isset($_GET['selectedcourseid'])`. Are you sure `$_GET['selectedcourseid']` is set too?

Comment: and what's about `$acceptmonth`?

Comment: Hi, I'm sure that $_GET['selectedcourseid'] is set. If it is not set, the page redirects to another page altogether.

$acceptmonth is anothe static variable

I'll just post the var_dump() results

Comment: Then I don't think you're giving us the full picture. As @aynber said, please edit your question and show us `var_dump($_GET);` and also `var_dump($openclose);`.